# Totals by day using SQL [mysql]

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is as follows:

```
datePickup           deliveryStatus    count 
2015-09-04 16:14:55  1                 NULL
2015-09-04 15:52:52  99                NULL
2015-09-04 12:47:55  2                 NULL
2015-09-05 06:14:55  99                NULL
2015-09-05 15:52:52  99                NULL
2015-09-05 17:47:55  99                NULL
2015-09-06 02:14:55  1                 NULL
2015-09-06 14:52:52  99                NULL
2015-09-06 17:47:55  99                NULL
```

And I wish to total deliveries by day if the delivery status is 99:

```
datePickup   count 
2015-09-04   1     
2015-09-05   3     
2015-09-06   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` with `DATE()` :

```
SELECT DATE(datePickup), count(*)
FROM yourtable
WHERE deliveryStatus=99
GROUP BY DATE(datePickup);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try DATE_FORMAT

```
select DATE_FORMAT(datePickup, '%Y-%m-%d'), count(*) where deliveryStatus = 99 group by DATE_FORMAT(datePickup, '%Y-%m-%d')
```